# REGEX and IP Addresses

Tags: regex, python-2.7, ip-address

The Exscript any_match() function uses regex to match patterns in strings and returns the results in a tuple.

I am attempting to match IP addresses in a traceroute output.  It works for the most part, but for some reason returns some extra values (in addition to the targeted addresses).  I would like some assistance in the correct regex to use that will return only the IP addresses without the extra values.
**Note:**I have googled and searched stackoverflow for regex patterns as well as studied the regex help page.  This is the closest regex that's worked so far.

```
def ios_commands(job, host, conn):        
conn.execute('terminal length 0')
conn.execute('tr {}'.format(DesAddr))
print('The results of the traceroute', repr(conn.response))
for hops in any_match(conn,r'(([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})'):
    hop_addresses = list(hops)
```

**OUTPUT**

### the string being searched

```
hostname>('The results of the traceroute', "'tr 192.33.12.4\\r\\nType escape sequence to abort.\\r\\nTracing the route to hostname (192.33.12.4)\\r\\nVRF info: (vrf in name/id, vrf out name/id)\\r\\n  1 hostname (192.32.0.174) 0 msec 0 msec 0 msec\\r\\n  2 hostname (192.32.0.190) 0 msec 0 msec 0 msec\\r\\n  3 192.33.226.225 [MPLS: Label 55 Exp 0] 0 msec 4 msec 0 msec\\r\\n  4 192.33.226.237 0 msec 0 msec 0 msec\\r\\n  5 hostname (192.33.12.4) 4 msec *  0 msec\\r\\nhostname>'")
```

---

```
['192.33.12.4', '12.'] #note the extra '12.' value

['192.33.12.4', '12.']

['192.32.0.174', '0.']

['192.32.0.190', '0.']

['192.33.226.225', '226.']

['192.33.226.237', '226.']

['192.33.12.4', '12.']
```

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 matching groups in your pattern. The first one (and outer one) is for the whole IP address; and the second group is repeated thrice:

```
([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}
```

Use non-capturing groups:

```
((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})
```